# nohup does not run in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a Dockerfile based on `public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2`. I am trying to run this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /tmp
echo 'before nohup'
nohup xvfb-run chromedriver --allowed-ips=127.0.0.1 &
echo 'after nohup'
disown
```

Locally I tested with `docker run --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/tmp,tmpfs-size=536870912 --read-only --rm serverless-chromedriver-dev:appimage` and it worked. On AWS Lambda, my logs show `["before nohup","after nohup"]` as the output of the script. However, `/tmp/nohup.out` does not exist and `ps aux` does not show chromedriver.

I also checked the values of `$PATH` and `/usr/bin/` is on iit where `nohup` and `su` both are. I verified `/tmp` is writable. There is space: `/dev/vdd 537560 1016 524708 1% /tmp`

Overall I am flabbergasted why there is a difference at all between local docker and AWS Lambda function. Wasn't the point of `docker` to avoid exactly this?

Comment: AWS implements its own disconnect handler which somehow still kills the process. I would try `setsid nohup <your command>` &

Comment: Alternatively this might work too. `nohup <your command> & disown $!`

Comment: Can't it be done without nohup by just putting the process in bg. Also disown su chrome.. would work. Screen is also an option but needs to be installed before.

Comment: Afaik Lambda support for Docker exists to solve problems around larger package sizes and offers Docker development workflow for those who prefer it. It doesn't dramatically change the nature of Lambda as short-duration FaaS with function freezes between invocations. What is your intention with the nohup chromedriver process?

Comment: Lambda is not a generic computing service; it is intended to run individual functions. Once the the function returns, the Lambda runtime freezes the container until the next invocation. Which means that you can't run anything in the background (well, you can, if you're willing to jump through some hoops, but that defeats the point of Lambda). Consider using AWS Batch or ECS/Fargate.